# How to create multiple JQuery.filer Upload form in the same page?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying Jquery.filer to create Drag & Drop Uploader in my page.

It works well but I need to use one more than one uploader for page.

If I create two or three input with different id and call the method filer()
on each of them, only the first works correctly.

Someone does know how to do that?

The page of the project is: http://filer.grandesign.md/

Comment: Post relevant code here at SO

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code HERE at SO - why not email the guy who wrote it?

Comment: Is the following code set up for each of your elements?

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#filer_input').filer();       
});

Comment: Yes, I call  $('#filer_input_1').filer();  $('#filer_input_2').filer();  etc...